# Hello, what does the word "are dogged" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-in-context

When many workers’ lives are dogged by insecurity and uncertainty about the future, consideration has to be given to the fact that workers are also consumers, and that if their working lives are very insecure, they might lack consumer confidence.

Answer (score 5):

One meaning of *dog* is *to follow someone closely* (like a bloodhound following their scent). Insecurity 'follows' the workers' lives; that is, they often experience it.

Comment: It's probably worth explicitly pointing out that most people ***like*** the "literal" usage (it's usually a good thing that "Man's best friend" follows him around, so he's always there when needed). But the ***figurative*** usage as cited here is, I think, ***always*** "negative, undesirable" - the nearest equivalent term being ***plagued***.